# How I can show my thousands of records in ScrollView

Tags: android, data-binding, binding, paging, data-paging

I am new to Android.I have stuck on one place,

I am fetching data from  server that have thousand of records.I am using Limit 0,50 in my Query.SO it is showing only 50 records,But if I don't use Limit My application goes to crash.What should I do to  show all my data in a List form.Is there any concept of Paging in Android or any other way.
Please suggest me the way.or links If anybody know it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

save data fetched from server into db, using cursor to read data from db or set cache

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a customized list adapter ? In the getView method, use a combination of convertView + view holder, as explained here : http://chrislee.kr/wp/2011/01/01/making-the-android-ui-fast-and-efficient-by-romain-guy/